# hide "Creating default object from empty value in" output

Tags: php, html, parsing, error-handling

I know this question has been asked about fixing this error but I don't want to fix it, I want to hide it.  I know the problem that is happening but basically, I don't care because the script works exactly how I want it to.

Depending on the which link the user clicks on, the next page parses the content and edits the HTML.  Sometimes, the HTML data doesn't contain a div which I'm specifying and that's ok with me.  So how can I hide it?  Using Simple HTML parser, for example, I have this code:

```
$boo->find('div[class*=container]', 0)->innertext = '';
```

which is saying that ALL classes containing the word "container" should change the innertext to nothing.  Basically getting rid of the data that I don't want.  But some page contents don't have any divs with container and I think that's why I'm getting this warning.  So what can I do to simply ignore it?  Is there a certain way I can phrase an if statement?  Please advise!

Comment: Turn off error reporting?

Comment: @jtheman The ceiling is dirty: Solution: don't ever look up again?

Comment: not turn it off but ignore this one...is that possible?

Comment: yes, just add a @ in front of it: `@$boo->find([...]`

Comment: wow...all that explaining and such a simple answer.  At least post it in the answer so I can except it for you so you get something out of it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
$element = $boo->find('div[class*=container]', 0);
if ($element) {
    $element->innertext = '';
}
```

or

```
foreach($boo->find('div[class*=container]') as $element) 
       $element->innertext = '';
```

Comment: The @ symbol in front of the statements worked.  But I think I'll use the if statement to check if it exists every time.  Thanks